# Зачем такое писать в книгах?

Tags: visual-basic

Всем привет, я недавно в итнернет-магащине купил книгу Visual Basic для **профессионалов**, расчитывая что это книга для более углублённого изучения, получил книгу начал читать и бувально одна четверть книги, рассказывают о том как объявиться переменную, как ей присвоить значение, что такое событие, как их вызывать и прочие... тогда напрашивается вопрос, почему книга называется Visual Basic для **профессионалов**, или такой вопрос, зачем профиссионалам рассказывать о том как объявить переменную? Просто хочется узнать к чему это? Просто это вижу уже не в первые...

Comment: Может быть там звёздочка малюсенькая стоит, а на последней странице написано "для профессионалов игорного бизнеса". Короче для других каких-нибудь профессионалов)

Comment: вы бы ссылку на книгу привели,или хотя бы автора

Comment: Это всего лишь реклама....лажа

Comment: А зачем задавать такой вопрос? Скачай другую книгу да не парься!

Comment: Зачем писать такое в книгах? Ответ "для объёма" подойдёт? А вообще "Visual Basic для профессионалов" -- уже само по себе определяет уровень профессионалов и книги для них.

Comment: @Angus123, если бы там было написано **для профанов**, то ее никто в руки бы не взял.

Comment: @avp, книги серии "для чайников", однако, расходятся многотысячными тиражами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит обращать внимания на подзаголовки и слоганы.

1. Это может быть просто название серии, семейства книг издательства, объединенных общим дизайном и объемом томов :)
2. Это может быть книга, в которой есть разделы, посвященные нетривиальным возможностям рассматриваемой технологии, но в целом рассчитанная на широкую, в том числе неподготовленную аудиторию.
3. Это может быть книга, рассчитанная на профессионалов, не знакомых с данной технологией вообще. Например, введение в Java для программистов C++.

Я давно уже редко приобретаю книги, а если делаю это, то только заранее ознакомившись с содержимым электронной версии и убедившись, что книга достойная. В конце концов, в магазине полистать книгу десять минут тоже никто не запретит.

Answer (score 1):

Ну непонятно же, что там конкретно. Может быть и вправду лажа, а может там, к примеру, рассказываются какие-нибудь глубокие подробности, аспекты работы более нижних уровней? Тогда, ИМХО, для профессионалов.